# How integrate vpn connector into phonegap apps in android?

Tags: java, android, cordova, vpn

For now, users of our apps have to download vpn connector apps and login vpn server before utilizing resources inside our private network,
so we want to lessen the steps before users begin to interact with our service.

And I wonder if there's any solution to integrate vpn server connector into phonegap apps in android,
especially when we want to support android platform without vpn service api?

Are there any libs or framework available for usage like this?

Do I have to dig into source of phonegap to implements vpn connector?

Thank you~